# P=NP when number of inputs that give 1 is bounded by polynomial

Tags: np-complete, np, satisfiability, p-vs-np

Suppose there exists some NP-complete problem such that the number of inputs that gives 1 as an output is bounded by a polynomial; that is, if the problem is $f \colon \{0, 1 \}^* \to \{0, 1\}$, then, for every $n$, $|\{ x \in \{0, 1 \}^n : f(x) = 1\}| \leq p(n)$ for some polynomial $p$. Then, I want to show that the existence of this problem implies $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP}$. Is it somehow related to LEXSAT?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahaney%27s_theorem

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, maybe I'm not yet aware of the proper rules of CS Stack Exchange, but why is this a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: Answers are usually longer.

Comment: @bernardosubercaseaux, you're welcome to write it as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result you are trying to prove is known as [Mahaney's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahaney%27s_theorem). It is covered by textbooks on complexity theory, and in many online lecture notes.

The proof in Jonathan Katz' [lecture notes](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/complexity/f05/lecture6.pdf) indeed uses LEXSAT.